# ParcelJS bundling error - favicon.ico: Invalid Version: undefined

Tags: javascript, parceljs

This is the first time I am using ParcelJS. I `npm` it following their instruction everything looks good.  So it would be the latest version. As soon as I run it against my project (a .html file with some js and css attached to it), I get this error.

`favicon.ico: Invalid Version: undefined`

I have tried to ask Google without much luck. Got any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using Parcel version `1.12.4` [this github issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/5943) is the reason why you got this error. It's not your fault.

You may try to pin your Parcel version as `1.12.3` in `package.json`:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "parcel": "1.12.3"
},
```

If your Parcel is installed globally, you may check your version of Parcel:

```sh
parcel --version
1.12.4
```

Uninstall `1.12.4` and reinstall `1.12.3`:

```
npm uninstall -g parcel-bundler
npm install -g parcel-bundler@1.12.3
```

Comment: Thank you Bemn. I confirm 1.12.3 works. Not sure why parcelJS would release a version 1.12.4 that doesn't work out of the box though, strange.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and first I installed   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.8" and it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the quite similar error because my IDE accidentally imported a non-existent module. I had been suffering for a few hours, before I noticed that Т_Т So if decisions don't solve your problem, maybe it will be your case. Just check imports

```
TypeError: Invalid Version: undefined at new SemVer
```

Answer (score 0):

[The Parcel lead's recommendation](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/5943#issuecomment-789080294) in the GitHub issue is to move to v2

```
npm uninstall -g parcel-bundler
npm install -g parcel
```